# Alternating sum over binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to follow a proof in a physics paper, but got stuck with the identity
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{k}{n-i}\frac{(m+i)!}{i!} = m!\binom{k-m-1}{n}.$$
I would be very grateful if you could shed light on this mystery.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please link the paper. Not only can this help people solve the question, but it will also help me motivate binomial coefficient identities next time I teach combinatorics :)

Comment: @darij grinberg : I have required this identity to follow a proof from [Atomic Coherent States in Quantum Optics](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.6.2211) by Arecchi, Courtens, Gilmore and Thomas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we  have   *[Chu-Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)* in disguise.

> Dividing the left hand side by $m!$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^i\binom{k}{n-i}\frac{(m+i)!}{i!m!}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{k}{n-i}\binom{m+i}{i}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{k}{n-i}\binom{-m-1}{i}\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{k-m-1}{n}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2)  we apply the *Chu-Vandermonde* identity.

Comment: I feel embarrassed to see this unfold that easily. Thank you very much!

Comment: @d-r-k: You're welcome and don't worry. It's just a matter of experience.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{i}{k \choose n - i}{\pars{m + i}! \over i!} = m!{k - m - 1 \choose n}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{i}{k \choose n - i}
{\pars{m + i}! \over i!}} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{i}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\bracks{z^{n - i}}\pars{1 + z}^{k}}^{\ds{k \choose n - i}}\,\,\,
\overbrace{m!{m + i \choose i}}^{\ds{\pars{m + i}! \over i!}}
\\[5mm] = &\
m!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{k}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{m + i \choose i}
\pars{-z}^{i}
\\[5mm] = &\
m!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{k}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}
\overbrace{{-m - i + i - 1 \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}}^{\ds{m + i \choose i}}
\,\,\,\pars{-z}^{i}
\\[5mm] = &\
m!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{k}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}
{-m - 1 \choose i}z^{i} =
m!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{k}\pars{1 + z}^{-m - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
m!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{k - m - 1} =
\bbx{m!{k - m - 1 \choose n}}
\end{align}